# Visual Studio 2010 Controller changes only pickup after Rebuild in MVC 4 Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I have to rebuild the project each time after making changes to the controllers for it to pick up and show when running the project.  Is there a setting VS2010 that's making this happen?  I'm using `[OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam = "none", Duration = 1, NoStore = true)]` for each method so I don't think it's the web server.  It doesn't even debug down into the controller unless I rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Any code (controllers, services, data layer items) are compiled into a .dll file which is what the server uses for processing.  The raw text files (what you are editing) are not used by the server.  Therefore, any change you make to any `.cs` or `.vb` file will always require a re-compilation.  This is also true for using the built-in VS web server (which, typically I get yelled at by VS saying "You can't modify this file while the debugger is running" or "the source file does not match the current debug file")

You can, however, modify views on the fly without recompiling in most cases.

Comment: Shouldn't VS be smart enough to know that you edited a `.cs` file in between debugging sessions?  This behavior isn't consistent with VS.  Usually if I stop debugging, make a change, then start debugging again `F5` it picks up the changes.  In this case, I need to `Rebuild` in between debugging sessions or the changes made in `.cs` aren't showing.  I'm always using the built in VS web server and haven't had this problem with other projects.  I'm not trying to modify the `.cs` file while the debugger is running, modifications are made before the debugging starts.

Comment: Debugging typically triggers a rebuild before the debugger starts.  Ensure that your MVC4 project is set as the start up project is the only things I can think of.  Your question made it seem you fired up the debugger, made some changes and then wondered why they weren't showing (without mentioning starting debug again) :)

Comment: It's the startup project.  No other projects are starting.